# Deadlock convert (or mod) to smart

Tags: lock, security, smart-switch

I want to convert my entry door to a smart lock, but I haven't found any that are compatible with a jimmy proof deadlock. I've attached an image of my deadlock, and I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction to a mod I could install onto it or replace this portion with? I'd like to keep the key portion the same if possible, and if not, I would just like to keep the deadlock style. Anyone know of any options I might have? I don't want to drill holes into the door, so the simpler the method the better.

[image: jimmy proof deadlock mul t lock]

Comment: Do you rent this property or own it?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica - own, why does that matter?